# Imitation Excel formulas

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I want to set a Excel cell two values.one is visible,another will show in the edit box when the cell activited.Just like a formula.,except the formula is a normal number.Can this work by vba?Can somebody help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula bar will always show the value of the cell.

The cell itself can have formatting applied that changes the display of the value. For example, the screenshot shows a cell with a custom number format of

`Cu\sto\m fo\r\m\at #`

[image]

The formula bar and the cell cannot contain two different values, not even with VBA.

Comment: Can you tell me how can do it as the screenshot?why the formula bar and the cell shows different values

Comment: I don't know what else to write. The cell has a custom format applied. The custom format syntax is right there in the post, above the screenshot. The line with the gray background. Which part are you struggling with?

Comment: Thank you so much,I know what you mean now.It's a good way,I'll try if I can do by it.Thank you.